# change svg-captcha font-family

Tags: angular, authentication, captcha

```
const svgCaptcha = require('svg-captcha');
 
const captchaOption = {
    size: 6,
    noise: 2,
    color: false,
    background: '#f0f0f0',
  };

const createdCaptcha = svgCaptcha.create(captchaOption);
```

Only a default font style is applying. I have to apply a different font style. How can I acheive that?

I tried fontFamily, font keywords nothing is worked. Finally I find svgCaptcha.loadFont().I don't know how to use it.